# Copy a file from a network folder using applescript

Tags: applescript

Iam very new to applescript and am currently trying to copy a file from a network share. I have an iMac server on my network and this script will be distributed to all the mac computers connected to it.

Below is the code i have at the moment :-

```
set mycopypath to "Volumes:Work Basket:LabRat:LabRat For Client Side.xlsx" as alias

--set mycopypath to choose file

tell application "Finder" to set startup_Disk to (name of startup disk)

set mypastepath to startup_Disk & ":Users:Arjun:Desktop:" as alias

tell application "Finder" to duplicate mycopypath to mypastepath with replacing
```

In the above code , 'Work Basket' in the 'mycopypath' is the shared network folder. Currently when i run this code i get an error stating - `File Volumes:Work Basket:LabRat:LabRat For Client Side.xlsx wasn’t found.`

But when i use the commented out part `set mycopypath to choose file` it works fine. Also, if i use the above code to copy paste a file from one location to another on the local computer itself, it works fine. The network folder "Work Basket" is mounted in both cases.

I'v been at it for quite a few hours and must have tried many combinations of file paths but haven't been able to find a solution.Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following solution:

When you only uncomment the `set mycopypath to choose file` and comment the rest, you will get the correct path as a result in the bottom half of Script Editor. (See red arrow in screenshot).

After that copy that path to the `set mycopypath to ""` part and restore the original comments. This should work.

[image]

**EDIT**

I believe this is how to mount a network disk:

```
tell application "Finder" to mount volume "Your disk path/name"
```

**EDIT 2**

Mounting a network disk with user and pass:

```
mount volume "afp://192.168.200.1/" as user name "your username" with password "your password"
```

Comment: Also, it would be great if someone could guide me on how to mount the "Work Basket" folder at the beginning of the code itself. If it would be better for me to create another post, i would be glad to do so.Thanks again :)

Comment: thanks for the quick revert. The problem is the file path i have to specify in the "tell application "Finder" to mount volume "Your disk path/name". How do i connect to the server as a registered user with the username and password and then mount the shared folder? I am marking the earlier question as answered. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike POSIX paths where a path starts always with a `/` representing the startup volume and a path to an external volume starts with `/Volumes`, HFS paths (colon separated) start always with a disk name.

This is a shorter version of your code, the Finder has a property `desktop`

```
set mycopypath to "Work Basket:LabRat:LabRat For Client Side.xlsx" as alias
tell application "Finder" to duplicate mycopypath to desktop with replacing
```